# Как прятать блок, если в области видимости появился другой

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Здравствуйте. Есть разметка:

```html
<div class="title_newnews">Заголовок</div>
```

И при листинге страницы, если мы находимся ниже этого блока(заголовок), появляется на странице другой блок:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
          $(window).scroll(function(){
                    
              var scrollTop2 = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop2;
     var top2 = $('.title_newnews').offset().top;

     if ( scrollTop2 > top2 ) { 
      $(".poloska").css("display", "block");
       } else { 
      $(".poloska").css("display", "none");
     };
          })
    
      })
```

На странице, ниже, есть еще один блок: `<div class="newblock"></div>`

Вопрос: Каким образом сделать, чтобы как только в области видимости появлялся блок `newblock` - блок **poloska** (который появляется как только мы находимся ниже блока *title_newnews*) - исчезал?

Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Comment: странная какая-то у вас разметка в примере, только 1 заголовок, блок poloska будет появляться обратно при прокрутке вверх?

Comment: @MasterAlex да, это все реализовано у меня. и блоков на старнице естественно больше. я только нужные тут указал, которые взаимодействуют с js

Comment: так, а в чём тогда проблема сделать наподобие того, как появляется блок poloska? `var top3 = $('.newblock').offset().top;` и условие поменять на обратное `if ( scrollTop2 > top3 ) { $(".poloska").css("display", "none"); }`

Comment: @MasterAlex при таком условии, блок исчезнет только после того, как  прогартаю страницу ниже блока **newblock** . А мне нужно чтобы блок  `poloska` исчезал сразу, как только в обасти видимости появлялся блок  **newblock**

Comment: вычислите высоту блока и вычитайте её из top3: `var top3 = $('.newblock').offset().top - $('.newblock').outerHeight()`

Comment: Хотя странно почему ниже блока, потому что `.offset().top` это как раз начало блока